# Detect whether or not cursor is in Text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cursor

I am writing a text editor in Python 3 with tkinter, and I'm trying to add an undo function, but in order to log the user's edits I need to log the edit when they type a letter. However, I don't want to log the typed letter if they have clicked out of the text widget. My question is this:

Can I detect whether or not the Text widget's cursor is in the widget? Is there an attribute on the text widget, or a bind I can put on the master window to detect if the cursor is in the text widget?

Comment: do you mean that you want to detect if the widget has "focus"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a widget has focus in Tkinter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385921/how-do-you-check-if-a-widget-has-focus-in-tkinter)

Comment: I really don't know what the "focus" is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your bindings are on the text widget, and if the focus is *not* on the text widget, your text widget will never see the keypress. Focus management is built in to Tkinter, so you shouldn't have to do anything.

To answer your specific question, you can use the method [focus_get](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_get-method) to retrieve the widget that currently has keyboard focus. You can also bind to `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>` to be notified when the widget gains or loses focus.

Also, are you aware that the text widget has a built-in undo facility? The New Mexico Tech website has a nice brief overview: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-undo-stack.html

Comment: Thank you. It works great, I didn't realize that you could even put binds on text widgets.