# Tkinter check which Entry last had focus

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a program that has a virtual keyboard I created using Tkinter.  The pages that have the keyboard enabled have entry widgets where the users need to input data.  I am using `pyautogui` as part of the virtual keyboard to simulate the keyboard presses, but my issue is the widget that is focused when a user presses on any of the buttons on the keyboard.  Since each keyboard button is a `ttk.Button` when they press the keys, the button has the focus, and not the Entry widget they had selected they were trying to put data in.

As such right now I have the method which runs the keypresses, calling a specific widget to become the focus before it does the key press.  Here's the code I have right now:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pyautogui

def drawKeyboard(parent):

    keyboardFrame = tk.Frame(parent)
    keyboardFrame.pack()

    keys = [
        [ ("Alpha Keys"),
          [ ('q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'),
            (' ', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l'),
            ('capslock', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'),
            ('delete', 'backspace', 'home', 'end')
          ]
        ],
        [ ("Numeric Keys"),
          [ ('7', '8', '9'),
            ('4', '5', '6'),
            ('1', '2', '3'),
            (' ', '0', ' ')
          ]
        ]
    ]

    for key_section in keys:
        sect_vals = key_section[1]
        sect_frame = tk.Frame(keyboardFrame)
        sect_frame.pack(side = 'left', expand = 'yes', fill = 'both', padx = 10, pady = 10, ipadx = 10, ipady = 10)
        for key_group in sect_vals:
            group_frame = tk.Frame(sect_frame)
            group_frame.pack(side = 'top', expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')
            for key in key_group:
                key = key.capitalize()
                if len(key) <= 1:
                    key_button = ttk.Button(group_frame, text = key, width = 4)
                else:
                    key_button = ttk.Button(group_frame, text = key.center(5, ' '))
                if ' ' in key:
                    key_button['state'] = 'disable'
                key_button['command'] = lambda q=key.lower(): key_command(q)
                key_button.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', expand = 'yes')

def key_command(event):
    entry1.focus()
    pyautogui.press(event)
    return

root = tk.Tk()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()
drawKeyboard(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Obviously manually calling `entry1.focus()` does me no good if I want to input data into `entry2`.  And calling `entry2.focus()` does no good if I want to put data into `entry1`.  So is there a way for me to every time one of my buttons is pressed check to see which Entry Widget last had focus?

I need to check for specifically entry widgets as the final screen will also have some radio buttons and such.  Thanks for your time

EDIT: I made a quick change to the code, exchanging the `Shift` key for the `Capslock` key.  I realized that the way my code worked Shift would never actually work since you couldn't exactly hold it down and press another button.

Comment: This is one of my biggest pet peeves with ttk, that the buttons steal the focus like this. I can't figure out why anyone would think this is a good idea.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah it's definitely an annoyance :\  I've been looking at pygtk, but don't want to implement it because I'd have to change around my whole program, which would be a huge hassle at this point.

Comment: You can set `takefocus=False` for the buttons, but then you also remove the ability to traverse the buttons using the keyboard. If you don't have a physical keyboard, I guess that's not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the attribute `takefocus` to `False` to prevent the buttons from taking focus. This has the unfortunate side effect of not being able to traverse the buttons using the keyboard (which might be ok, since you're in a no-keyboard situation)

```
...
    key_button = ttk.Button(..., takefocus=False)
...
def key_command(event):
    entry = root.focus_get()
    entry.insert("end", event)
    pyautogui.press(event)
    return
```

Another solution is to add a binding on the `<FocusIn>` event where you can  save the widget in a global variable.

```
def key_command(event):
    focused_entry.insert("end", event)
    pyautogui.press(event)
    return

def remember_focus(event):
    global focused_entry
    focused_entry = event.widget

entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", remember_focus)
entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", remember_focus)
```

If you have many entry widgets, you can do a class binding on the `Entry` class instead:

```
root.bind_class("Entry", "<FocusIn>", remember_focus)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This actually works perfectly (the `takefocus = False` part).  My program will eventually be implemented on a tablet, so I don't need to worry about not being able to traverse the buttons with a keyboard :)

Comment: Hey Bryan. Can you change `takefocus` back to `True` in the case of a keyboard being connected. Just a hypothetical question but I am interested just the same. Or maybe have a event monitor that turns `takefocus` to True or False depending on if the user is trying to use the keyboard or the on screen keyboard?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: yes, you can change it as often as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will find two methods useful and they are described in this post:

[How do you check if a widget has focus in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385921/how-do-you-check-if-a-widget-has-focus-in-tkinter)

1. Bind your entry boxes to Enter key. When enter is pressed call the handling function and store which entry has a focus in a globally accessible variable like self.entry_focus in case you are buildng a class or just entry_focus which will be declared at the beginning of the script in the module scope level. When handling the event you can get info which widget called it by accessing event object which is being passed to the handler. Use event.widget and root.focus_get method for that.
2. Bind Enter to the root item. Then use focus_get method to check where the focus is every time enter was pressed no matter where the mouse cursor or focus really is.

See the code in the post above. Everything will be clear.

Good luck!