# How to call and close a virtual keyboard made by Tkinter using touchscreen display

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem with opening and closing the virtual keyboard made with Tkinter. I'm creating a GUI the user will browse it using touchscreen display and the user needs to input on entries.

I've tried `var_name.bind('FocusIn', callback)` to call the virtual keyboard and `var_name.bind('FocusOut',callback)` to close the virtual keyboard but when I used both the virtual keyboard is opening and then closing right away.

I hope you guys can help me here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def select(entry, value, event):
    focused_entry.insert("end", event)
    pyautogui.press(event)
    global uppercase
    uppercase = False

    if value == "Space":
        value = ' '
    elif value == 'Enter':
        value = '\n'
    elif value == 'Tab':
        value = '\t'

    if value == "Backspace":
        if isinstance(entry, tk.Entry):
            entry.delete(len(entry.get())-1, 'end')
        #elif isinstance(entry, tk.Text):
        else: # tk.Text
            entry.delete('end - 2c', 'end')
    elif value in ('Caps Lock', 'Shift'):
        uppercase = not uppercase # change True to False, or False to True
    else:
        if uppercase:
            value = value.upper()
        entry.insert('end', value)
    return

def create(root, entry):
    alphabets = [
        ['`','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','-','=','Backspace'],
        ['Tab','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',"\\"],
        ['Caps Lock','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';',"'",'Enter'],
        ['Shift','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.','/','Shift'],
        ['Space']
    ]    

    global window
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.configure(background="cornflowerblue")
    window.geometry("+0+483")
    window.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.7)

    for y, row in enumerate(alphabets):

        x = 0

        #for x, text in enumerate(row):
        for text in row:

            if text in ('Enter', 'Shift'):
                width = 18
                columnspan = 2
            elif text == 'Space':
                width = 124
                columnspan = 16
            elif text == 'Backspace':
                width = 10
                columnspan = 1
            elif text == '\\':
                width = 10
                columnspan = 1
            elif text == 'Tab':
                width = 10
                columnspan = 1
            elif text == '`':
                width = 10
                columnspan = 1
            elif text == 'Caps Lock':
                width = 10
                columnspan = 1
            else:                
                width = 4
                columnspan = 1

            tk.Button(window, text=text, width=width, 
                      command=lambda value=text: select(entry, value),
                      padx=3, pady=3, bd=12, bg="black", fg="white", takefocus = False
                     ).grid(row=y, column=x, columnspan=columnspan)

            x+= columnspan


# --- main ---

def remember_focus(event):
    global focused_entry
    focused_entry = event.widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test Keyboard')

    label = tk.Label(root, text='Test Keyboard')
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

    entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
    entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", remember_focus)

    entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')
    entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", remember_focus)

    text1 = tk.Text(root)
    text1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='news')
    text1.bind("<FocusIn>", remember_focus)

    root.mainloop()
```

thank you sir @furas for helping me create the virtual keyboard.
I edited the code and tried Bryan Oakley's answer here [Tkinter check which Entry last had focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237883/tkinter-check-which-entry-last-had-focus)

Comment: Relevant [`[python][tkinter] virtual keyboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+virtual+keyboard)

Comment: Strip down your example code to a empty `tk.Frame` to show your attempt.

Comment: the problem might be with your `command`.

Comment: Actually it could have been a lot easier for people to solve your issue if you had posted a minimal example of your code.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad The OP simple want to `deiconify` the `Toplevel` at event `'<FocusIn>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: call and close a virtual keyboard using touchscreen display

Instead of *call and close*, Instantiate your virtual keyboard once and use the `Toplevel` methodes `.deiconify()` and `.withdraw()`.

Don't bind the event `'<FocusIn>'` to every input widget, bind to **application level** using `bind_all(...`.

---

**Reference**:

- [Events and Bindings - Section: Instance and Class Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

  > Use `bind_all` to create a binding to handle the event at application level.
- [`bind_all(sequence=None, func=None, add=None)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind_all-method)

  > Adds an event binding to the application level.

---

**Core point**:

- Use `.bind_all('<FocusIn>', ...` to `.deiconify()`
- Use `.bind_all('<Button-1>', ...` to `.withdraw()`

```
# VKeyboard.py
import tkinter as tk


class VKeyboard(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Don't show the 'Toplevel' at instantiation
        super().withdraw()
                
        self.create()
        
        # Process all application == parent events
        parent.bind_all('<FocusIn>', self.on_event, add='+')
        parent.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.on_event, add='+')
    
    def on_event(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        
        # Don't process the own Button
        if w.master is not self:
            w_class_name = w.winfo_class()
            
            if w_class_name in ('Entry',):
                if self.state() == 'withdrawn':
                    self.deiconify()
                
                self.entry = w
            
            elif w_class_name in ('Button',):
                super().withdraw()
                w.focus_force()

    def create(self):
        # define the virtual keyboard `tk.Button`
        pass
```

> **Usage**

```
import tkinter as tk
from VKeyboard import VKeyboard


class Kiosk(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        VKeyboard(self)

        tk.Entry(root).grid()
        tk.Button(root, text='withdraw').grid()
                 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Kiosk().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: root does not exist. Should it be root = super().__init__()