# communication between tkinter toplevels

Tags: python, tkinter, communication

I'm working on a little project and made a little on-screen keyboard as a tkinter Toplevel

my application is buildt like this:

- Root-Window (Tk-Widget)

  - input 1 (Entry-Widget)
  - input 2 (Entry-Widget)
  - input 3 (Text-Widget)
  - on_screen-keyboard (Toplevel-Widget)

the Toplevel-Widget contains Buttons, with callbacks that should enter text in the entries (just like keyboard-Buttons)

What I want is a communication between children of the keyboard/the keyboard and **the last active input-Widget**. My Problem is, that I don't know, how to say the keyboard, to which input-Widget it should send the message.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.active_input = tk.Variable(value=None)
        ttk.Button(self, text="show Keyboard", command=lambda: Keyboard(self)).pack()
        self.text = tk.StringVar(value="")
        self.input1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.input1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: self.active_input.set(self.input1))
        self.input2 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.input2.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: self.active_input.set(self.input2))
        self.input3 = tk.Text(self, height=3, width=15)
        self.input3.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: self.active_input.set(self.input3))
        self.input1.pack()
        self.input3.pack()
        self.input2.pack()

class Keyboard(tk.Toplevel):

    OPENED = False
    NAME = "- Keyboard -"
    NUM = [{"text":"1", "width":1},
           {"text":"2", "width":1},
           {"text":"3", "width":2}]
    CHAR= [{"text":"A", "width":1},
           {"text":"B", "width":1},
           {"text":"C", "width":2}]

    def __init__(self, master):
        if not Keyboard.OPENED:
            Keyboard.OPENED = True
            print("keyboard opened!")
            self.master = master
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
            self.title(self.NAME)
            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

            self.keyb_nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
            self.keyb_nb.pack()

            self.num_tab = ttk.Frame(self.keyb_nb)
            self.createPad(self.num_tab, Keyboard.NUM,2)
            self.keyb_nb.add(self.num_tab, text="123")

            self.char_tab = ttk.Frame(self.keyb_nb)
            self.createPad(self.char_tab, Keyboard.CHAR, 2)
            self.keyb_nb.add(self.char_tab, text="ABC")

    def createPad(self, master, pad:list, max_col):
        self.co_count = 0
        self.ro = 1
        for button in pad:
            button["id"] = ttk.Button(master, width=6*button["width"], text=button["text"], command=self.bclicked(button))
            if self.co_count >= max_col:
                self.ro = self.ro + 1
                self.co_count = 0
            button["id"].grid(row=self.ro, columnspan=button["width"], column=self.co_count)
            self.co_count = self.co_count+button["width"]

    def bclicked(self, button:dict):
        """
        reciver = self.master.active_input #I think the Problem here is, that  the variable contains a string, not a widget
        reciever.focus_force()
        reciever.insert(index=tk.INSERT, string=button["text"])
        """
        pass

    def close(self):
        Keyboard.OPENED = False
        self.destroy()
        print("keyboard closed!")


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Here the init of the Mainwindow and the bclicked of the Keyboard class are important...

the code is debug-ready

I would prefer a solution, similar to the communication in the internet (sender=button, receiver-id, message), but very welcome every working solution

btw: I'm also looking for a solution, how I don't have to force the input to focus and the Toplevel stays an the highest layer of the screen (that if I focus the Tk-Widget/one of the inputs/the button, the keyboard will stay in front of it)

SUMMARY: how do I find out, which of the 3 input-widgets was active at last, when the keyboard-toplevel has already the focus?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call and close a virtual keyboard made by Tkinter using touchscreen display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136473/how-to-call-and-close-a-virtual-keyboard-made-by-tkinter-using-touchscreen-displ)

Comment: You should use `lambda` in `.bind(...)`.

Comment: im sorry, but this doesn't answer my question

Comment: and yes, usually i use lambda, i just forgott it while coding this example, because my code is more complex than the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code maybe could have a better construction.(But I didn't revise your code construction.)

Followed by your code,I use a global variable.And fix some errors in your code.And it could work normally in my computer.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.active_input = tk.Variable(value=None)
        ttk.Button(self, text="show Keyboard", command=lambda: Keyboard(self)).pack()
        global focusedWidget
        focusedWidget = None
        self.text = tk.StringVar(value="")
        self.input1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.input1.bind("<FocusIn>", self.getFocusWidget)
        self.input2 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.input2.bind("<FocusIn>", self.getFocusWidget)
        self.input3 = tk.Text(self, height=3, width=15)
        self.input3.bind("<FocusIn>", self.getFocusWidget)
        self.input1.pack()
        self.input3.pack()
        self.input2.pack()

    def getFocusWidget(self,event): # this function could be a static function
        global focusedWidget
        focusedWidget = event.widget

class Keyboard(tk.Toplevel):

    OPENED = False
    NAME = "- Keyboard -"
    NUM = [{"text":"1", "width":1},
           {"text":"2", "width":1},
           {"text":"3", "width":2}]
    CHAR= [{"text":"A", "width":1},
           {"text":"B", "width":1},
           {"text":"C", "width":2}]

    def __init__(self, master):
        if not Keyboard.OPENED:
            Keyboard.OPENED = True
            print("keyboard opened!")
            self.master = master
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
            self.title(self.NAME)
            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

            self.keyb_nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
            self.keyb_nb.pack()

            self.num_tab = ttk.Frame(self.keyb_nb)
            self.createPad(self.num_tab, Keyboard.NUM,2)
            self.keyb_nb.add(self.num_tab, text="123")

            self.char_tab = ttk.Frame(self.keyb_nb)
            self.createPad(self.char_tab, Keyboard.CHAR, 2)
            self.keyb_nb.add(self.char_tab, text="ABC")

    def createPad(self, master, pad:list, max_col):
        self.co_count = 0
        self.ro = 1
        for button in pad:
            button["id"] = ttk.Button(master, width=6*button["width"], text=button["text"], command=lambda button=button:self.bclicked(button)) # this lambda expression has some errors.
            if self.co_count >= max_col:
                self.ro = self.ro + 1
                self.co_count = 0
            button["id"].grid(row=self.ro, columnspan=button["width"], column=self.co_count)
            self.co_count = self.co_count+button["width"]

    def bclicked(self, button:dict):
        global focusedWidget

        """
        reciver = self.master.active_input #I think the Problem here is, that  the variable contains a string, not a widget
        reciever.focus_force()
        reciever.insert(index=tk.INSERT, string=button["text"])
        """
        if not focusedWidget: # If user hasn't click a entry or text widget.
            print("Please select a entry or text")
            return
        if focusedWidget.widgetName=='ttk::entry': # use if statement to check the type of selected entry.
            focusedWidget.insert(index=tk.INSERT,string=button["text"])
        else:
            focusedWidget.insert("end",button["text"])


    def close(self):
        Keyboard.OPENED = False
        self.destroy()
        print("keyboard closed!")


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you. I found one more error: to use partial()  instead of lambda in the button command will work better. therefore you have to import partial from functools

Comment: @silvapuer Yes,That's your error in your post code.Using lambda is okay.You can read it in [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: thats realy great! Thank you

Comment: do u think, it's possible to solve this without a global variable?

Comment: @silvapuer Yes,alex's answer didn't use global variable.

Comment: @silvapuer Sum up,to make small revision and avoid global variable,you can def  `self.focusedWidget` variable in class `Mainwindow`.And call `bclicked` use `self.master.focusedWidget` in class `Keyboard`.

Answer (score 1):

I may made more changes than needed, but mainly focus on the method `keyboard_triger()` and `pass_key_to_master()`, this two use the idea that the variable `master` implements, having access to call methods out of scope.
Olso the method `set_focused_object()` stores a reference to the last object beeng focused, note than it stores the widget and not the event, it's easyer than searching each time the object

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def keyboard_triger(self, key):
        # to identify wath object is just use
        # isinstance(self.active_input, ttk.Entry)
        self.active_input.insert(tk.END, key)

    def new_keyboard(self):
        Keyboard(self)

    def set_focused_object(self, event):
        self.active_input = event.widget

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.active_input = None

        ttk.Button(self, text="Show Keyboard", command=self.new_keyboard).pack()

        self.input1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.input1.bind("<FocusIn>", self.set_focused_object)
        self.input1.pack()

        self.input2 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.input2.bind("<FocusIn>", self.set_focused_object)
        self.input2.pack()

        self.input3 = tk.Text(self, height=3, width=15)
        self.input3.bind("<FocusIn>", self.set_focused_object)
        self.input3.pack()

class Keyboard(tk.Toplevel):

    def pass_key_to_master(self, key):
        self.master.keyboard_triger(key)

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.title('Keyboard')

        # this way of agruping keys stores the kwags
        # of the drawing method
        keys = {
            'A': {'x': 0, 'y': 0},
            'B': {'x': 20, 'y': 20},
            'C': {'x': 50, 'y': 50}
        }

        # expected structure
        # {string key: reference to the button}
        self.buttons = {}
        for i in keys:
            self.buttons[i] = tk.Button(  # i=i is required to make a instance
                self, text=i, command=lambda i=i: self.pass_key_to_master(i)
            )
            self.buttons[i].place(**keys[i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```